# Flutter: flutter_local_notifications delete old notifications

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I'm using flutter_local_notifications to handle notifications, and everything is working fine, however, I just discovered the method `getActiveNotifications()` and as it turns out, all of my notifications are stored there (even ones set in the past).

My question is, isn't it ideal for old notifications that did their job to be erased on their own? Why does this function return the old ones?

I tried removing them by using `onDidReceiveLocalNotification`, but the event is never called.

Here's my code:

```html
class NotificationService {
      final notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      final StreamController<String?> onNotificationClick = StreamController();

      Future initializetimezone() async {
        tz.initializeTimeZones();
      }

      Future<void> initNotification() async {
        await initializetimezone();

        const initializationSettingsAndroid =
            AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/flutter_logo');

        final initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
          requestAlertPermission: true,
          requestBadgePermission: true,
          requestSoundPermission: true,
          onDidReceiveLocalNotification: _onDidReceiveLocalNotification, // this is where I try to remove the old notifications. It's never invoked.
        );

        var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
          android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
          iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
        );

        final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
            await notificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
        final didNotificationLaunchApp =
            notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;

        // was the app was launched via notification?
        if (didNotificationLaunchApp) {
          var notificationResponse =
              notificationAppLaunchDetails!.notificationResponse!;
          onSelectNotification(notificationResponse);
        } else {
          await notificationsPlugin.initialize(
            initializationSettings,
            onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onSelectNotification,
          );
        }
        
        void _onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
          int id,
          String? title,
          String? body,
          String? payload,
        ) {
          print("You will never see this line");
          notificationsPlugin.cancel(id); // remove notification
        }
      }
```